# How do I create loops to substitute for hard-coding window coordinates using Zelle's 'graphics.py' library?

Tags: python, loops, coordinates

**Problem:** I waste a great deal of time and create buggy, bloated code by hand-coding my coordinates. I need help learning how to substitute this verbose code for loop structures that will give the same result. Currently, the x and y coordinates are stored in separate arrays named xCoords and yCoords, respectively. How can I simplify this and write a more elegant version of this program?

[Note: This is my *first* StackOverflow post. Please inform me of style, etiquette, or posting errors and I'll fix them. This forum has been indispensable for me and I appreciate everyone's help.]

**Relevant Details:**

- I am creating a two-player GUI game called "Dot Matrix". The users interact with the window using mouse clicks. An online version of this game can be found [at this link](http://www.papg.com/show?1TX6). Plotting the coordinate points is important because it orients the players and is the entirety of the game board. This code snippet doesn't include the actual game logic because I haven't written it yet.
- I am using a [graphics library](http://mcsp.wartburg.edu/zelle/python/) from John Zelle's *Python Programming* book.

**Source Code:**

```
    # dotmatrix.py
    # Dot Matrix Game
    # Michael Morelli
    # mmorelli at live dot com
    # Created: 03-24-13 with Python 2.7.3 and PyScripter

    from graphics import *

    win = GraphWin("Dot Matrix", 500, 500)
    win.setCoords(0.0, 0.0, 10.0, 10.0)
    win.setBackground("white")

    xCoords = [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,
               2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,
               3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,
               4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,
               5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,
               6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,
               7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,
               8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,
               9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9]

    yCoords = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,
               1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,
               1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,
               1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,
               1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,
               1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,
               1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,
               1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,
               1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]

    for i in range(81):
        Text(Point(xCoords[i], yCoords[i]), "*").draw(win)
        i+=1 # This for loop iterates through each of the coordinate arrays
             # and plots an * asterisk at each coordinate locus. There is a plot()
             # method included with the graphics library, but it plots single-pixel
             # points and are hardly visible. I do not think this will affect the game.

    input("Press <Enter> to quit.")
    win.close()
```

Thank you for your help!
-Michael

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code logic seems equivalent to using two nested loops:

```
for xCoord in xrange(1, 10):
    for yCoord in xrange(1, 10):
        Text(Point(xCoord , yCoord ), "*").draw(win)
```

Comment: What I especially like about your comment is that it includes the xrange iteration function instead of range. I looked up why xrange is preferable and it was a great teaching moment. With range() it creates the entire list so there's a latency and memory issue; but with xrange() it generates one item at a time then discards and moves on. Thanks much! Made me a better programmer!